# Run Snakemake rule one sample at a time

Tags: bash, loops, gpu, snakemake, genome

I'm creating a Snakemake workflow that will wrap up some of the [tools in the nvidia clara parabricks pipelines](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/docs/parabricks/quickstart-guide/software-overview/standalone-tools-overview/). Because these tools run on GPU's, they typically can only handle one sample at a time, otherwise the GPU will run out of memory. However, Snakemake shoves all the samples through to Parabricks at one time - seemingly unaware of the GPU memory limits. One solution would be to tell Snakemake to process one sample at a time, thus the question:

**How do I get Snakemake to process one sample at a time?**

*Because parabricks is a licensed product (and therefore not necessarily reproducible), I will show an example of the parabricks rule I am trying to run (pbrun fastq2bam), as well as a minimal reproducible example using open source software (fastqc) which we can work on/from*

### My parabricks rule - pbrun fastq2bam

Snakefile:

```sh
# Define samples from fastq dir using wildcards
SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards("../fastq/{sample}_1.filt.fastq.gz")

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}_recalibrated.bam", sample = SAMPLES)

rule pbrun_fq2bam:
    input:
        R1 = "../fastq/{sample}_1.filt.fastq.gz",
        R2 = "../fastq/{sample}_2.filt.fastq.gz"
    output:
        bam = "{sample}_recalibrated.bam",
        recal = "{sample}_recal.txt"
    shell:
        "pbrun fq2bam --ref human_g1k_v37_decoy.fasta --in-fq {input.R1} {input.R2} --knownSites dbsnp_138.b37.vcf --out-bam {output.bam} --out-recal {output.recal}"
```

Run command:

```sh
snakemake -j 32 --use-conda
```

Error when four samples/exomes are present in the `../fastq/` directory:

```sh
GPU-BWA mem
ProgressMeter   Reads           Base Pairs Aligned
cudaSafeCall() failed at ParaBricks/src/samGenerator.cu:782 : out of memory
cudaSafeCall() failed at ParaBricks/src/samGenerator.cu:782 : out of memory
cudaSafeCall() failed at ParaBricks/src/chainGenerator.cu:185 : out of memory
cudaSafeCall() failed at ParaBricks/src/chainGenerator.cu:185 : out of memory
cudaSafeCall() failed at ParaBricks/src/chainGenerator.cu:185 : out of memory
cudaSafeCall() failed at ParaBricks/src/chainGenerator.cu:183 : out of memory
cudaSafeCall() failed at ParaBricks/src/chainGenerator.cu:185 : out of memory
cudaSafeCall() failed at ParaBricks/src/chainGenerator.cu:183 : out of memory
```

### Minimal example - fastqc

Get data:

```sh
mkdir ../fastq/
gsutil cp -r gs://genomics-public-data/gatk-examples/example1/NA19913/* ../fastq/
```

Snakefile:

```sh
SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards("../fastq/{sample}_1.filt.fastq.gz")

rule all:
    input:
        expand(["{sample}_1.filt_fastqc.html", "{sample}_2.filt_fastqc.html"], sample = SAMPLES),
        expand(["{sample}_1.filt_fastqc.zip", "{sample}_2.filt_fastqc.zip"], sample = SAMPLES)

rule fastqc:
    input:
        R1 = "../fastq/{sample}_1.filt.fastq.gz",
        R2 = "../fastq/{sample}_2.filt.fastq.gz"
    output:
        html = ["{sample}_1.filt_fastqc.html", "{sample}_2.filt_fastqc.html"],
        zip = ["{sample}_1.filt_fastqc.zip", "{sample}_2.filt_fastqc.zip"]
    conda:
        "fastqc.yaml"
    shell:
        "fastqc {input.R1} {input.R2} --outdir ."
```

fastqc.yaml:

```sh
channels:
  - bioconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - bioconda::fastqc =0.11.9
```

Run command:

```sh
snakemake -j 32 --use-conda
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to expand on the answer of @jafors. Probably what is better to do instead of limiting the memory, you can make a gpu resource:

```
rule pbrun_fq2bam:
...
    resources:
        gpu=1
```

And then run your snakemake with `--resources gpu=1`

This case you can still use memory and threads for other rules and every resource describes what it is.

Comment: Nice! This is indeed better suited to the use-case.

Comment: Thanks @Maarten-vd-Sande for pointing out this much simpler approach! It works and perfectly and will allow the pipeline to scale up when more gpus are available!

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding `threads: 32` to your rule, so snakemake will use all given cores on one rule iteration/sample.

Memory can also be restricted using sth. like

```
resources:
    mem_mb=100
```

in the rule and `--resources mem_mb=100` in the snakemake call. This would restrict the rule to use at most 100MB memory.

Comment: Thanks @jafors, this would also be another great way to approach this! Actually setting the memory limits could be beneficial over setting the number of GPU's in the case where the rule was going to be used to analyse WGS or WES data, or WGS data from species with genomes of very variables sizes. Since memory is the limiting factor here, the rule would be more flexible in these circumstances where memory use per sample would be variable.

Comment: @LeahKemp know that you can set multiple resources for a single rule. So nothing is stopping you from using threads, but also both mem_gb, and gpu as resources.