# snakemake job submission in sequential manner

Tags: python-3.x, snakemake

I wrote a snakemake pipeline for performing sortmeRNA version 4.2.0. The pipeline is as follows, and works perfectly when I run it for 1 sample:

```
SAMPLES = ['A']
READS=["R1", "R2"]

rule all:
    input: 
        expand("Clean/{exp}.clean.{read}.fastq.gz", exp = SAMPLES, read = READS)

rule sortmeRNA:
    input:
        one = "{SAMPLES}.R1.trimd.fastq.gz",
        two = "{SAMPLES}.R2.trimd.fastq.gz"
    output:
        one = "Clean/{SAMPLES}.clean.R1.fastq.gz",
        two = "Clean/{SAMPLES}.clean.R2.fastq.gz"
        
    params:
        bac16s = "rRNA_databases/silva-bac-16s-id90.fasta",
        bac23s = "rRNA_databases/silva-bac-23s-id98.fasta",
        acc = "--num_alignments 1 --threads 16 --fastx --other -v"
    message: "---Sorting reads with rRNA databases---"

    shell:'''
        rm -rf {SAMPLES}/kvdb;\
        sortmerna -ref {params.bac16s} -ref {params.bac23s}\
            -reads {input.one} -reads {input.two}\
            --workdir {SAMPLES}\
            {params.acc} && \
            echo "deinterleaving...." &&\
            bash deinterleave_fastq.sh < {SAMPLES}/out/other.fastq {output.one} {output.two} compress && \
            echo "moving log and removing folder.." && mkdir -p Sort_log && mv {SAMPLES}/out/aligned.log Sort_log/{SAMPLES}.log &&\
            rm -rf {SAMPLES}
    '''
```

The last section does the following:

> 1. purges {SAMPLES}/kvdb if it exists
> 2. Runs sortmeRNA
> 3. Checks for {SAMPLES}/out/other.fastq
> 4. runs 'deinterleave_fastq.sh' and puts the R1 and R2 in Folder called 'Clean'
> 5. Moves the 'aligned.log' to Sort_log and renames it to {SAMPLES}.log
> 6. Removes the {SAMPLES} folder.

Essentially, what happens is that for each 'SAMPLE' it filters out the fastq files and retains only the output required and purges the other folders.

It is submitted with:

```
snakemake -ps sortmeRNAv4.2.0.snakefile --cluster "sbatch -n 1 --time=02:00:00 -c 16" --jobs 1
```

The problem arises, when I do the following:

```
SAMPLES = ['A','B']

snakemake -ps sortmeRNAv4.2.0.snakefile --cluster "sbatch -n 1 --time=02:00:00 -c 16" --jobs 2
```

The job gets submitted, however it gets into the error

> rm -rf A B

I understand that, SAMPLES are replaced by A & B and since it is not yet generated and everytime the folders get purged and it the condition can never be satisfied. How do I modify the code such that, each job is run in parallel without conflict ? i.e at any given time, the command should only be

set of batch commands with

> SAMPLES = A, complete the process
> SAMPLES = B, complete the process

and not mix it up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Snakemake rule one sample at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63733419/run-snakemake-rule-one-sample-at-a-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `{SAMPLES}` in your inputs and outputs is a wildcard. In the shell it is read as the global variable defined above the rule.

You should use `{wildcards.SAMPLES}` in the shell section:

```
rule sortmeRNA:
    input:
        one = "{SAMPLES}.R1.trimd.fastq.gz",
        two = "{SAMPLES}.R2.trimd.fastq.gz"
    output:
        one = "Clean/{SAMPLES}.clean.R1.fastq.gz",
        two = "Clean/{SAMPLES}.clean.R2.fastq.gz"
        
    params:
        bac16s = "rRNA_databases/silva-bac-16s-id90.fasta",
        bac23s = "rRNA_databases/silva-bac-23s-id98.fasta",
        acc = "--num_alignments 1 --threads 16 --fastx --other -v"
    message: "---Sorting reads with rRNA databases---"

    shell:'''
        rm -rf {wildcards.SAMPLES}/kvdb;\
        sortmerna -ref {params.bac16s} -ref {params.bac23s}\
            -reads {input.one} -reads {input.two}\
            --workdir {wildcards.SAMPLES}\
            {params.acc} && \
            echo "deinterleaving...." &&\
            bash deinterleave_fastq.sh < {wildcards.SAMPLES}/out/other.fastq {output.one} {output.two} compress && \
            echo "moving log and removing folder.." && mkdir -p Sort_log && mv {wildcards.SAMPLES}/out/aligned.log Sort_log/{wildcards.SAMPLES}.log &&\
            rm -rf {wildcards.SAMPLES}
    '''
```

You also should avoid naming a wildcard as a global python variable. Your rule treats one sample at a time, so just call it `{sample}` and leave the `SAMPLES` for the python variable defined above the rules.

Comment: Yes. I learnt that, wildcards need to be used when executing inside shell.